# Egorov's theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Egorov's theorem states that if I have a finite measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and measurable functions $f,f_n:\Omega\to \mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise almost everywhere, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find a set $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\mu(A)<\varepsilon$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A^c$. Does this hold true if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\infty$ with positive measure as well? I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041303/using-egorovs-theorem-when-the-sequence-of-functions-converges-pointwise-to-inf) on the subject, which states that it works in the case that the sequence converges to infinity almost everywhere but I havent found the result for the case that $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=\infty\}$ and $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n<\infty\}$ both have positive measure. I am particularly interested in the case that \begin{align*}\mu(\{\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=\infty\})+\mu(\{\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0\}=\mu(\Omega).\end{align*}
My idea is to use Egorov's theorem and the result from the post respectively on the restrictions of $\mu,f,(f_n)$ on the sets $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=\infty\}$ and $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n<\infty\}$. Does this work?

Comment: What do you mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ ? because this is just $f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fixed it I just forgot the subscript n

Comment: There is a general statement of Egorov's theorem for functions with values in a separable metric space.

Comment: @P.P.Tuong Yeah I found that result earlier but I did not think that this was applicable here. So this means that the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of the extended real numbers is induced by a metric?

Comment: $\overline{R}$ with $d(x,y)=|\arctan(y)-\arctan(x)|$ is a complete separable  metric space. You can use Egorov's for convergence in complete separable metric spaces.